# In Ruby is there a built-in method that requires keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I know that in Ruby 2.0 and later you can have keyword arguments, so that you can define a method like this:

```
def foo(inline_argument, *args, **kwargs, &block)
  puts 'bar'
end
```

However, I was wondering: is there a built-in method which makes use of keyword arguments?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: I must write a `method_missing` in a custom class and I am not sure if I have to implement it like `def method_missing(meth, *args, **kwargs, &block)` or just `def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)`. I mean, I don't know how likely it is to receive a method with keyword arguments.

Comment: Since the syntax allows it, you should be expecting to encounter such usage regardless of whether there is actual use at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby keyword arguments of method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463053/ruby-keyword-arguments-of-method)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - the other question does not answer my question and it's definitely not a duplicate, as it doesn't ask the same thing as I do. Even if it answered my question (which is doesn't), that would be by chance and not because of duplicate.

Comment: There are probably some built-in methods that *use* keyword arguments, but not require them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I `cd`ed into my Ruby install directory and ran `grep -r ', \*\*' .` and discovered that yes, there are methods in the stdlib that use `**kwargs`, but only in the `open3.rb` library.

```
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def popen3(*cmd, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def popen2(*cmd, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def popen2e(*cmd, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def capture3(*cmd, stdin_data: '', binmode: false, **opts)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def capture2(*cmd, stdin_data: '', binmode: false, **opts)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def capture2e(*cmd, stdin_data: '', binmode: false, **opts)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def pipeline_rw(*cmds, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def pipeline_r(*cmds, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def pipeline_w(*cmds, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def pipeline_start(*cmds, **opts, &block)
./lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:  def pipeline(*cmds, **opts)
```

**EDIT**:

At @mdesantis suggestion, I did an [MRI identifier search](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?v=2.1.0-p0&i=rb_get_kwargs) for `rb_get_kwargs`; turns out there are at least a few methods in the C core library that use keyword args.

```
Dir.new( string, encoding: enc ) -> aDir

Array#sample(n, random: rng) -> new_ary
Array#shuffle!(random: rng) -> ary

GC.start(full_mark: false) -> nil
```

Comment: Unfortunately this check doesn't consider that the core methods' majority is implemented in C

Comment: Nice; I would add [`GC.start`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/GC.html#method-c-start)