# Handling keyword parameters in `method_missing`

Tags: ruby

When I write `method_missing` in a custom class I am not sure if I can implement it `def method_missing(meth, *args, **kwargs, &block)` or just `def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)`. (The docs for [method_missing](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) do not cover keyword arguments.) How are keyword parameters handled in `missing_method`?

(N.B. This is mentioned in a comment on the question [In Ruby is there a built-in method that requires keyword arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19938640/575530), but the answer does not cover the question in the comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method_missing` works just like any other method in this regard. When you use a double splat it will slurp any  keyword arguments and `kwargs` will always be a hash:

```ruby
module Foo
  def self.method_missing(*args, **kwargs, &block)
    kwargs
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):049:0> Foo.bar(baz: 'Hello World')
=> {:baz=>"Hello World"}
```